# Computer turns off after 30s of booting Windows 10 or Linux

Tags: boot, crash

As of yesterday, my computer started turning itself off about 30s after I boot either Linux Mint or Windows 10 (both still in the loading mode, I never reach a usable OS).

I have removed the PCI card I had (only the GPU is installed at the moment), the second hard drive, the CD/DVD reader, it still crashes. I have even tried removing the main hard drive and booting from a bootable USB drive with Linux Mint on it, but the computer still turns itself off.

Memtest86+ can run for hours on end without the computer crashing and without detecting any errors. The CPU temperature stayed constant at about 70°C during this, so I don't think the crash comes from a CPU overheating problem.

I did not do any recent changes to the computer that would have created the issue.

I am a bit clueless as to what the problem could be and how I could fix it.

Comment: May be it is power supply unit? Can you test with another PSU? And how you measure CPU temperature while booting? Or it is only while memtest86 is working?

Comment: @MiniMax I don't have another working PSU available right now, I will try to get access to one to try. Yes, the temperature was measured during memtest86

Comment: Also, I just run `memtest86+` on my old testing PC (`AMD Athlon II X2 240`) and CPU temperature is about 45 degrees C. And on another PC running Ubuntu 16.04 CPU's (`i5 2500`) temperature is about 40 degrees C. So, may be you have overheating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a hardware issue. 
I think, try to remove all hdd, ssd, dvd etc. devices, and run a live linux from usb stick (as far as I understand you, when you tried live system, you left one of hdds connected)
If it works... my first idea is a failing PSU. The second: defective mainboard.

Comment: I also tried booting from the live USB with all the HDDs disconnected and it still crashed. I don't have another working PSU at the moment but I will try to get access to one to test.

Comment: I went to buy a new PSU today and now the computer works like a charm. Thank you!